# My code keeps looping

Tags: lua

I'm very new to Lua and my code is confusing me, I'm making a maze game just for practise and I've come across an error, everytime I run my code it loops, instead of going to the next part. I will appreciate any help given.

My code:

```
print ("Welcome to the maze")

input = ""
while input ~= "leave" do
    print ("What do you want to do first? Leave or inspect?")
    input = io.read()

    if input == "inspect" then
        print (" You venture towards the maze.")
    end

    if input == "leave" then
        print ("You turn around and run.")
    end
end

input = ""
while input ~= "turn around" do
    print ("There is a path, which do you want to take, left, right or turn around?")
    input = io.read()

    if input == "left" then
        print (" You turn left to the dark trees.")
    end

    if input == "right" then
        print ("You turn right to the light pathway.")
    end

    if input == "turn around" then
        print ("You turn around and run.")
    end
end
```

Comment: Im not sure why the code has messed up, but that isnt how it is, its normal on SciTE for me.

Comment: do you come out of the first while?

Comment: from your first while loop you get an print ("What do you want to do first? Leave or inspect?"). If you now put in "leave", will he go out of this loop and go in the second loop and ask you print ("There is a path, which do you want to take, left, right or turn around?") ?

Comment: I havent got past that point yet :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the logic here is slightly skewed (once you `turn around` you'll be asked to `inspect` or `leave` again), here's how you would get to that second part - it needs to occur if you choose to `inspect` the maze:

```
print ("Welcome to the maze")

input = ""
while input ~= "leave" do
    print ("What do you want to do first? Leave or inspect?")
    input = io.read()

    if input == "inspect" then
        print (" You venture towards the maze.")
        while input ~= "turn around" do
            print ("There is a path, which do you want to take, left, right or turn around?")
            input = io.read()

            if input == "left" then
                print (" You turn left to the dark trees.")
            end

            if input == "right" then
                print ("You turn right to the light pathway.")
            end

            if input == "turn around" then
                print ("You turn around and run.")
            end
        end
    end

    if input == "leave" then
        print ("You turn around and run.")
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm very confused on how you got to that point... Please explain.

Comment: Think about it logically. You come upon a maze - you have two choices, inspect, or leave.  If you inspect, you'll enter the maze. You can't leave the maze and then turn left or right in the maze. That's what your first while loop is saying - type `leave` to get to the next section of code.

There's still a logical problem here because at any time you `turn around`, you'll be able to magically `leave` the maze on the next input rather than needing to find your way back to the start.

Comment: So shall i scratch this project and do something different?

Comment: Quitting isn't really the solution if it's going to help you learn. Try to figure it out. Come up with a new design for the solution if you need to.

Comment: But if my code isnt logical then its not going to help  me in the future when i attempt to put my skills to proper use.

Comment: So change your code to make it logical. You want to make a maze game. Think about the interactions the user will have. Make use cases. Draw flow diagrams. It's a good exercise to help you think like a developer. Just my recommendation, however, you're free to do whatever you want.